# Should I consider LINQ to Entities?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I'm just starting with the Microsoft stack doing a web site in ASP.Net MVC and so far using LINQ to SQL. Should I consider LINQ to Entities? Does it have anything special to offer? If so, what?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been investigating this exact thing myself.

Here are my findings in a nutshell

**LINQ to SQL**

Advantages

- Incredibly easy to use

Disadvantages

- Cannot update the diagram from the database, you have to delete your class and then drag it back onto the diagram from the DB.  This is a real pain if you modified the diagram at all.
- Not actively being developed any more (they will develop Entity Framework instead).

**Entity Framework**

Advantages

- Has much more functionality (Table inheritance, etc...)
- Can be updated from the database
- Has multiple providers (not just SQL)
- The model can be queried without using LINQ, you can use Entity SQL
- Microsoft seems to be investing heavily on it and proposing it as the main way to access a database: [Update on LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities Roadmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx), [Clarifying the message on L2S Futures](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/31/clarifying-the-message-on-l2s-futures.aspx).

Disadvantages

- Complicated and a lot less intuitive

**Conclusion**

I personally decided to go down the route of using the Entity Framework.  I bought a book and have read the online material and I am very impressed with it.  It took a little extra effort to learn, but the benefits really are great.

Comment: It doesn't support POCO - that's why I'm not going to touch it.

Comment: L2S also has the advantage of being pretty damn fast, almost as fast as native ADO.NET when using compiled queries. It is also much more light weight than EF.

For small projects with simple requirements I would probably use L2S. Also, L2S is good enough to drive StackOverflow.

EF version 4 do look very interesting though.

Answer (score 0):

First, Linq to entity offer many to many functionnality

Second, Microsoft would put more time into it

and I'm sure many other good reason

Answer (score 0):

Although LINQ to SQL isn't going to go away, Microsoft is betting on LINQ to Entities. For that reason, I would go with LINQ to Entities.

The ADO.NET Team Blog has more information on the issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/31/clarifying-the-message-on-l2s-futures.aspx

I've listed these posts chronologically, but be sure to read at least the last one - it's actually the most important one.